# How to solve this Oracle SQL issue?

Tags: oracle, table-alias

```
select * from(select e.*,dense_rank() over(partition by dept_name order by salary desc) as Top_salaried
from employee e) as B where Top_salaried <= 3;
```

I have the above query that fetches top 3 salary from each dept
above is working fine PostgreSQL

when i try to exec the same in oracle it throws error

> SQL command not properly ended

Can anyone please help me with this
how do i need to modify it in oracle

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, **table** aliases don't allow the `AS` keyword (but column aliases do, such as `as top_salaried`). So:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT e.*,
               DENSE_RANK ()
                  OVER (PARTITION BY dept_name ORDER BY salary DESC)   AS top_salaried
          FROM employee e) b   --> no "as" here
 WHERE top_salaried <= 3;
```